# Unstable after moving headless server from usb-hdd to usb pendrive

Tags: 12.04, server, usb-drive

Ubuntu server 12.04.1 running from usb-hdd is rock solid for months. After copying the partitions to a Kingston usb pendrive the system will only run for 3-4 days before some services fail.

Is running 12.04.1 from usb pendrive a viable approach?

How do I troubleshoot the problem?

In the meanwhile, I have reverted back to usb-hdd. Willing to buy a usb pendrive that is known to work. Recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Your pendrive is just flaky.  I don't have a specific recommendation for brand, aside from "spend a little more" and specifically look for one advertising *fast* USB2.0 or (better) USB3.0 access.  You generally get what you pay for, and cheap pendrives aren't really designed or tested for long-term connection with heavy usage.